# Am I Doing Something Wrong here Unity 3D

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, shuffle

I've been stuck on this script for about some weeks. I have this script where as to the items that are on a list shuffle every time a new game starts. I don't know why but I can't seem to shuffle an item list at all. Please help, and tested it for yourself if you can. Also please explain to me what might be the problem or what I can do to fix it, I'm still pretty new to this.

```
`using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RayCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pickupDistance;
    public List<Item> items;
    public List<Item> finalItems;

    #region Unity
    void Start ()
    {
        Screen.lockCursor = true;
        // Do a while loop until finalItems contains 5 Items
        while (finalItems.Count < 5) {
            Item newItem = items[Random.Range(0, items.Count)];
            if (!finalItems.Contains(newItem)) {
                finalItems.Add(newItem);
                }
            items.Clear();
            }
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, pickupDistance))
        {
            foreach(Item item in finalItems)
            {

                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                    if (item.gameObject.Equals(hit.collider.gameObject))
                {
                    numItemsCollected++;
                    item.Collect();
                    break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {

        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(130,400,100,130));
        {
            GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            {
        if (numItemsCollected < items.Count)
        {
            foreach (Item item in finalItems)

                        GUILayout.Label(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", items.Collected ? "" + items.password: " ", items.name ));
        }
        else
        {
            GUILayout.Label("You Win!");
        }
            }
            GUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private
    private int numItemsCollected;
    #endregion
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public int password;

    public bool Collected { get; private set; }



    public void Collect()
    {
        Collected = true;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void passwordNumber()
    {
        password = 0;
        Collected = true;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }


}

`
```

Comment: i dont really understand what your problem is. Can you maybe explain in more detail 1) what you want the script to do, and 2) what the script does that you didnt expect?

Comment: Ok so the script is basically making a list of items from 1-10. Every time you click on an item that you have found within the list, it will give you a random number, which means you collect it and the number will do something else which isnt important. What my prblem is that the items doesnt shuffle everytime a new game has started. I  dont want the list being the same everytime you start the game. Is that a bit better??

Comment: I don't know if I have done something wrong but it will not randomize the item list. I don't understand where to go. If you need more details just let me know.

Comment: Before answering, I want to clarify something. The variable `items` is a `List` but I don't see your code adding any list items to it. And you always clear it at the end of the loop, meaning `items.Count` will stay zero no matter how many times you loop. So how can the loop finish if the `Random.Range` always returns 0?

Comment: I actually meant to take the items clear off just for that reason. Somebody suggested it but it didn't work.I see, are you saying that I should switch item to items in my foreach statement?

Answer (score 0):

This example is too complicated, and has a lot of unrelated code to the question you seem to be asking. As a basic strategy, you should try to isolate the code you think has a problem, fix that problem, then apply it to the larger case.

For example, your basic logic has at least one error: Random.Range is *inclusive*, so you could possibly have an out-of-bounds index unless you use "index.Count-1".

Here's an example that creates a list of 5 random items from a larger "original" list. You should be able to apply this to your code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RandomList : MonoBehaviour {

  public List <int> originals = new List<int>();
  public List <int> randomized = new List<int>();
  public int desiredNumberOfRandomInts = 5;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
      originals.Add(i);
    }
    while(randomized.Count < desiredNumberOfRandomInts) {
      int randomSelection = originals[Random.Range(0, originals.Count-1)];
      if (!randomized.Contains(randomSelection)) {
        randomized.Add(randomSelection);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the `items.Clear()` might work, with the reason I explained in my comment.

```
while (finalItems.Count < 5) {
   Item newItem = items[Random.Range(0, items.Count)];
   if (!finalItems.Contains(newItem)) {
       finalItems.Add(newItem);
   }
}
```

But still, I'm assuming you already have list of `items` somewhere already (and the list must be >5 since you will loop minimum 5 times). If you don't `items.Count` will still stay 0, and making your random become `Random.Range(0,0)`.